# PHP Add ID and String into Array, in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I need to add a UNIQUE ID and a string that is with that ID , into an array. This array needs to be updated too. Example:
ID NAME[(3,Flor)(5,Dries)] Then I need to have a check when I want to insert a new value in this array if the ID already is in the array or not. I currently have this:

```
               $werknemers= [];
               while($werknemer= $werknemersql->fetch_assoc()){
                   $werknemerid = $werknemer['userid'];
                   $naam = $werknemer['name'] ." " . $werknemer['familyname'];
                   array_push($werknemers, array("id" => $werknemerid, "naam" => $naam ));

               }
               echo $werknemers[1][1];
```

Comment: did you mean `"id" => $werknemerid`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: To check if a an `id` value was already in the array you'd probably use something like `in_array($id, array_column($werknemers, 'id'))`

Comment: If you want to check, it is better to use indexes : an index lookup is way more efficient that value search

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique to achieve that is to always update the array, with a consistent index:

```
$werknemers = [];
while($werknemer = $werknemersql->fetch_assoc()){
    $werknemerid = $werknemer['userid'];
    $naam = $werknemer['name'] . " " . $werknemer['familyname'];

    $index = $werknemerid . '.' . $naam;
    $werknemers[$index] = ["id" => $werknemerid, "naam" => $naam];
}
```

And then, if necessary, get rid of the indexes:

```
$werknemers = array_values($werknemers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$werknemers= [];
while($werknemer= $werknemersql->fetch_assoc()){
    $werknemers[$werknemer['userid']] = $werknemer['name'] . " " . $werknemer['familyname'];
}
```

Use id as index and it's solved :)